# Stripe payload coming through empty [Object object] causing error codes in transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, stripe-payments

I'm following along the stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) for fulfilling orders on my subscription app and can't get the stripe CLI to send verified 200 status events.

I backed up and believe it's because my payload is coming through totally empty as `[Object object]` because I can't figure out where to drop in the bodyParser. The stripe docs call for it as part of the route (below) but I've separated my routes and controller functions.

Here's how it looks in the stripe docs:

**Stripe function**

```
// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body;

  console.log("Got payload: " + payload);

  response.status(200);
});
```

My code is separated into a router function and a controller function so here is how I've tried to recreate it in my app:

**Router**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const JSONBodyParser = bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'});

router.route('/stripe/webhook')
    .post( JSONBodyParser, catchAsync( users.stripeWebhook))
```

**Controller**

```
module.exports.stripeWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    console.log("Got payload: " + payload);

    res.status(200);
};
```

The `console.log(payload)` renders as `[Object object]` but my understanding is there should be customer data attached to the payload. According to the stripe docs, I should see:

- A checkout.session.completed in the stripe listen output
- A print statement from your server’s event logs with the checkout.session.completed event

The connection is there because I've setup my stripe cli to listen for the route and log events in the terminal. Transaction events are coming through but are failing to post at the moment because I don't have switches setup in my controller function yet.. again, I've backed up a little bit to try to understand why I'm missing data in my `payload`.

**App.js (added late)**

```
 app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }, {
     // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
     // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
     verify: function (req, res, buf) {
         if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("users/stripe/webhook")) {
             req.rawBody = buf.toString();
              }
          },
      })
 );
```

Any ideas how I could get the `bodyParser` to work so I can start debugging?

Comment: Do you mean to use bodyParser.json()?

Comment: Hi @zemaj - I don't, I just named my variable that way (since I the application type was JSON). Any ideas how I could get the bodyParser to work?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a couple of problems you are facing.

The docs seem to be out of date for node as `body-parser` is packaged with express. And although you seem to be using the package correctly, I would recommend using the `json` body parser from express if you are using a version greater than `4.16`.

```
import express, { json } from 'express';

const app = express();
app.post('/stripe/webhook', json(), (req, res) => { /* req.body is parsed json. */ })
```

Also there should be 4 events that you are getting back to your webhook. You should be able to check this with `req.data.type` to see which event came back. And you can get the event data in `req.body.data`.

The 4 events are:

```
checkout.session.completed
payment_intent.created
payment_intent.succeeded
charge.succeded
```

Console log is just printing out [Object object] because that is how your object is being converted to a string using the `.toString` method. You can use `util.inspect` to see all of the properties on the object.

```
import util from 'util';
...
console.log('Got payload:' + util.inspect(payload, { showHidden: true, depth: null })); // This will show you the whole payload in a formatted way.
```

I would recommend using inspect on the payload and it will give you formatted json that you can easily debug.

Another option would be to use `JSON.stringify` to see what the json payload would look like.

Comment: Hi @tim117 - JSON.stringify worked in that I got all the data I needed and can see "customer" in the object. If I try `const payload = JSON.stringify(req.body.customer)` it comes back as `undefined`. Do you know how I could get the customer field? (Also, I haven't tried the util attempt yet - have to run somewhere and will give it a try when I'm back but thanks again for the comment!).

Comment: if you’re able to see the json payload with `JSON.stringify`, your body parser is set up correctly, so I think you’re focused on the wrong problem. The event object that stripe returns has the event data stored in `req.body.data`. I believe the path for `customer` is `req.body.data.object.customer`. If you try the `inspect` util, it will format this nicely for you to look through and you can find exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using your middleware incorrectly here:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const JSONBodyParser = bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'});
```

Try this:

```
router.route('/stripe/webhook')
    .post( bodyParser.json(), catchAsync( users.stripeWebhook))
```

Alternatively you can use the middleware at a higher level (assuming express).

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Also worth noting that Express 4.16+ has this built in and can be called like so:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Here is a reference: https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c

Comment: Hi @zemaj thanks for the reply. I tried your route attempt of `.post( bodyParser.json(), catchAsync( users.stripeWebhook))` but received `[ Object object ] as the output. I also went to add the body parser express call and realized I already have a version of that in my app.js from when I attempted this build six weeks ago. I've edited and added the code to my question above. Still no luck with this setup.